# Is it possible to use a value from another table within the same query?

Tags: mysql, select

I have different user roles, buyers and sellers. Where their information is stored is dependent on their role. So a buyers info would be stored in the buyers table and a sellers in the sellers table. Also a users role is saved in the newsletter table as well.

Each table has a common column called join_id, which is their membership id from the members table.

So now my question is it possible to write something along the lines of this...

```
SELECT newsletter.email, newsletter.role as role, role.first_name
FROM newsletter INNER JOIN role ON newsletter.join_id = role.join_id
WHERE newsletter.active = 1
```

Comment: Took me a while to understand your question, but I see it now. You have a `buyers` table and a `sellers` table. Then your `newsletter` table has a column "role" which holds a string, either "buyer" or "seller" then you need to join the newsletter table to either the `buyer` or `seller` table based on the string the `newsletter.role` field contains for that particular member. Ah.

Comment: Please don't edit my post, you made it so someone just learning wouldn't have any idea what you are talking about. As it is now it is easy to follow by a beginner.

Comment: I strongly disagree, it might be clear to you since you understand your own situation, but to any onlooker, all they see is a query which doesn't work lacking an explanation what it should do, along with bad grammar the whole question making it hard to follow, and the query doesn't even fit on 1 page since it's all on 1 line. My edits helped the quality of the question for usage on stackoverflow, but if you wanna argue about it, please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We have established policies here. If you don't want me to edit your question, it's unclear, so why answer it?

Comment: As an English major, I can tell you no newbie was going to be able understand anything with your edit. Bad grammar or not. Keeping it simple without using "jargon" is usually best, and the reason it was written the way it was.

Comment: You could have rolled back to revision 2 so I can at least read the query...

Comment: It wasn't an option, I looked for it specifically.

Comment: Odd, should have been an option. I rolled it back to revision 2 so the query is easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the query like so:

```
SELECT newsletter.email, newsletter.role,
IF(newsletter.role='buyer' AND buyers.join_id IS NOT NULL,buyers.first_name,
  IF(newsletter.role='seller' AND sellers.join_id IS NOT NULL,sellers.first_name,
  'Not Found')
) AS first_name
FROM newsletter
LEFT JOIN buyers ON newsletter.join_id = buyers.join_id
LEFT JOIN sellers ON newsletter.join_id = sellers.join_id
WHERE newsletter.active = 1
```

The idea is to use `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN` so we include NULL data, then we join onto both the `buyers` table and the `sellers` table. Once joined, we use if-statements to select what we want based on the role of the user in the newsletter log.

**Edit:**

If you don't want to see "Not Found" entries like in the above, you could skip records where the newsletter.join_id doesn't match up to a buyer or seller. But then you won't see the newsletter for that particular log. You'd do this by adjusting your `WHERE`:

```
SELECT newsletter.email, newsletter.role,
IF(newsletter.role='buyer',buyers.first_name,sellers.first_name) AS first_name
FROM newsletter
LEFT JOIN buyers ON newsletter.join_id = buyers.join_id
LEFT JOIN sellers ON newsletter.join_id = sellers.join_id
WHERE newsletter.active = 1 AND (
  (newsletter.role='buyer' AND buyers.join_id IS NOT NULL)
    OR
  (newsletter.role='seller' AND sellers.join_id IS NOT NULL)
)
```

The above is probably easier to work with, especially if you need to select multiple columns from either the buyer/seller table.

**Edit 2:**

For the case of admin, you'd just need to add `OR newsletter.role='admin'` to the condition, then it would look for your information in the sellers table. Or, you could hard-code your name info the if-statement:

```
SELECT newsletter.email, newsletter.role, (
CASE newsletter.role
WHEN 'buyer' THEN buyers.first_name
WHEN 'seller' THEN sellers.first_name
WHEN 'admin' THEN 'Hard-code your name here'
ELSE 'unknown' END
) AS first_name
FROM newsletter
LEFT JOIN buyers ON newsletter.join_id = buyers.join_id
LEFT JOIN sellers ON newsletter.join_id = sellers.join_id
WHERE newsletter.active = 1 AND (
  (newsletter.role='buyer' AND buyers.join_id IS NOT NULL)
    OR
  (newsletter.role='seller' AND sellers.join_id IS NOT NULL)
    OR newsletter.role='admin'
)
```

Comment: There should only be one not found case... and that is my own personal login as my role is "admin". If there is I have MUCH bigger problems! LOL and my membership doesn't get logged anywhere but the members table. All users are logged as either buyer or seller, and it is checked multiple times through out the 3 step sign up process....

Comment: For the case of the admin role, if you want to include yourself in the results, then you'd add `OR newsletter.role='admin'` to the WHERE. But then it would look for you in the sellers table due to how the if-statement is written. So you can adjust that too if you want to use a hard-coded value for your role. Ooor, you could create an "admin" table if you're going to have more than one admin account around, then `LEFT JOIN` onto that too and complicate your if-statements more. If the SQL gets too complicated, can avoid JOINS and just do separate queries from PHP.

Comment: For this I am the one writing the newsletter so I am not concerned with receiving it too. As for there being more than one admin, that is a big nope! My controlling nature will never allow that. LOL I had it as 2 separate queries but the new server it is on does not have mysqlnd enabled and getting everything into an associative array that was acceptable to swiftmailer was a BIG pia issue. So combining everything into one big query was the only reasonably simple answer.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then my second block of code should be fine.